# GraphQL with React: How to grab image source

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I am unable to get the image location to show up in `<img src="" />` when I try and pull it in via GraphQL. It's empty in the DOM.

All of my images are stored in `/src/static/img/` in the directory tree.

I have a `LOCATIONS` array with a group of objects as such:

```
const LOCATIONS = [
    {
        name: 'Atlanta',
        geo: 'United States',
        image: 'img/flags/us_flag.svg'
    },
    {
        name: 'New York',
        geo: 'United States',
        image: 'img/flags/us_flag.svg'
    },
]
```

And my schema looks like this:

```
const schema = buildASTSchema(gql`
    type Query {
        locations: [Location]
        location(id: ID!): Location
    }

    type Location {
        id: ID
        name: String
        geo: String
        image: String
    }
`);

const mapLocation = (location, id) =>
    location && { id, ...location };

const root = {
    locations: () => LOCATIONS.map(mapLocation),
    location: ({ id }) => mapLocation(LOCATIONS[id], id)
};
```

When loading the data onto the page, everything works except for the image:

```
export const GET_LOCATIONS = gql`
    query GetLocations {
        locations {
            id
            name
            geo
            image
        }
    }
`;

export default () => (
    <Query query={GET_LOCATIONS}>
        {({ loading, data }) =>
            !loading && (
                <ContainerDiv>
                    {data.locations.map(location => (
                        <FlexDiv key={location.id}>
                            <div>
                                <Svg src={location.image} />
                            </div>
                            <TextDiv>
                                <h3>{location.name}</h3>
                                <p>{location.geo}</p>
                            </TextDiv>
                        </FlexDiv>
                    ))}
                </ContainerDiv>
            )
        }
    </Query>
);
```

I'm using styled-components but that `<Svg>` is an image tag:

```
const Svg = styled.img`
    width: 8rem;
    min-width: 4rem;
`;
```

Comment: api tested in playground ?

Comment: It works if I put the image files in the /public directory. I think Webpack is having a problem with them, or better yet, I'm doin' it wrong :)